# Why are there no java compiler alternatives to allow new functionality?

Tags: java

For example, a new java compiler could allow for some breaking backwards compatibility to allow for things like overloading on generic types like:

```
void foo(List<String> arr);
void foo(List<Integer> arr);
```

Or to allow things like generics over primitive types

```
void foo(List<int> arr);
```

Now I am not suggesting these are trivial changes, or that everyone would even use such a compiler, but I was curious why I could not find ANY alternatives to javac. Even if you never modified the bytecode spec, some of these changes (and others) could be implemented purely at compile time. If nothing else, it could allow a nice testbed to merge changes back to mainline in some fashion (I get that changing the semantics of the language means it is no longer "Java", but let's call it J++ or something).

I like Java's backwards compatibility first mentality, but I was surprised this is not an approach people have taken over completely new languages like Kotlin/Ceylon/etc.

Is there more going on here that prevents this from happening?

Comment: No, you could not implement either of those changes without changing the byte code spec. Also, Java is difficult enough to implement that there's little desire for a non-compliant compiler or JVM. As for a test bed, you can take the existing open source code, make your changes, and try it out. Furthermore, Java emphasizes cross-compatibility, and any code using these extra features would be totally incompatible.

Comment: @raptortech97 can you explain in more detail why you would have to modify the bytecode spec?

Comment: Technically, you could devise a compiler of Java++ to JVM bytecode. You can compile just about anything to JVM bytecode if you really wanted to. However, since Java's rules about methods and classes are actually implemented at the bytecode level you'd have to work around those rules, and forgo compatibility with previously compiled code.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the sort of thing you are positing does not exist:

- http://pizzacompiler.sourceforge.net/

it is an existence proof of what you're looking for (but from 12 years ago -- many of the features in that "extended Java compiler" eventually migrated into the real Java compiler).  In fact, Java keeps evolving at a reasonable (okay, that's debatable) pace, so "extensions" to the language get considered and implemented in Java (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)

But more broadly, I think you could argue that Scala (http://www.scala-lang.org/) meets your definition.  Its broken backwards compatibility at the source level (the language is *totally* different), but generates output that runs on a vanilla JVM, and, more impressively, it is interoperable with standard Java libraries.

All the other JVM-based languages (like groovy, jruby, jpython, etc) also fall in this category.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages for a more comprehensive list.  (Note that there are a couple entries on that Wikipedia page that claim to be supersets of Java, even.)

I think anyone that would take the time to implement a Java++ would probably want to fix a lot of stuff.  And would end up creating something completely different.  A lot has been learned about language design in the last 20 years, and the JVM provides a compatibility mechanism that doesn't require source code compatibility.

Comment: When you mention scala, you can also mention clojure. It "breaks" the source-level even more and is equally compatible on the jvm level.

Comment: @P.T. The Pizza compiler is exactly the kind of thing I was looking to find. I wonder why there are not more projects like this today?

Comment: Just for trivia: Pizza was designed and implemented by Martin Odersky. Later on, Martin Odersky designed and implemented GenericJava, a superset of Java with generics. Sun hired Martin Odersky to design Generics for Java, and the GenericJava compiler actually became the standard `javac` compiler shipped with the SDK as early as Java 1.2 (with the bits about generics disabled). Later on, a modified design of generics (with wildcards being the main new addition) was released with Java 1.5. Odersky, of course, went on to first design Funnel, then Scala, but his compiler still ships with Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2004 [Microsoft did have a product called J++.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_J%2B%2B) It got Microsoft involved in a bitter court battle with Sun Microsystems which Microsoft lost. A ton of stuff in the Java eco-system is heavily protected by intellectual property and trademark law, and Oracle has an army of lawyers to enforce it. One of Java's big selling points has been cross platform/cross-vendor compatibility. As someone who is currently trying to get a thick stack of libraries to all build nicely on Linux using GCC and on OS X using Clang I kind of see the value in that.

Comment: This is interesting, however, it appears Microsoft was sued due to trademark violation per the terms of the license they received from Sun at the time. If such a project were called FooLanguage I'm not sure if this would be the case. Any more insight to this?

Comment: Because at some point you are going to say "compatible with Java" at which point Oracles's lawyer's are going to be all over you because they have a legally established process over what constitutes "compatible with java". And if you aren't going to say "compatible with Java" then you might just as well develop the language to your own specs and taste, as Microsoft did with C#.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to P.T. answer above. Scala as a functional programming language which compiles to Java bytcode (so uses JVM) allows some fancy FP footwork but either way the answer resolves to a hack. here is a link to a previous asked similar question for Scala:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982552/scala-method-overloading-over-generic-types

I would be hesitant to suggest Java 8 may be able to provide a similar hack given functions are now treated as first class citizens and can be passed around as arguments much like Scala.